# Swift Struct Identity

Tags: swift

I have a following struct which defines a shoppingList.

```
struct ShoppingList {

    var shoppingListId :NSNumber
    var title :String
}

let shoppingList = ShoppingList(shoppingListId: NSNumber, title: String) // I don't want to assign shoppingListId
```

Now, the problem is that it auto-generates the constructors which takes in the shoppingListId as parameter. Since shoppingListId is an identity or unique key I don't want to pass in with the constructor. It will be set later by the ShoppingListService after inserting shoppingList into the database.

Is this a place where class will make more sense than structures?

UPDATE:

```
struct ShoppingList {

    var shoppingListId :NSNumber
    var title :String

    init(title :String) {

        self.title = title
        // but now I have to assign the shoppingListId here unless I make it NSNumber? nullable
    }

}

let shoppingList = ShoppingList(title: "Hello World")
```

UPDATE 3:

```
 let shoppingList = ShoppingList()

// THE FOLLOWING CODE WILL NOT WORK SINCE IT REQUIRES THE shoppingList to // BE var instead of let

            shoppingList.shoppingListId = NSNumber(int: results.intForColumn("shoppingListId"))
            shoppingList.title = results.stringForColumn("title")
            shoppingLists.append(shoppingList)
```

Comment: you can just define your own `init` to prevent this automatic behavior. `structs` in swift will implicitly have their own constructors unless you set your own. edit: check out Default Initializers section in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203

Comment: you could, for example, define a default value for those properties to 0 and empty string, have the init simply be `init() { }` and then just have a `func` to assign those values later, or access them directly as `ShoppingList().title`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the default constructor, then make one of your own. However, it is important to keep in mind that unless your property is an Optional, it has to be initialized to some value. In this case, you will have to give shoppingListId a value, or you will need to make it an Optional. Also, I don't see any reason why a class would be better than a struct for this scenario.

```
struct ShoppingList {

    var shoppingListId: NSNumber
    var title: String

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
        shoppingListId = NSNumber(integer: 0)
    }
}

let newList = ShoppingList(title: "Groceries")
```

**Update:**
Just saw you updated your question. If you are not able to pick a reasonable initial value for your shoppingListId, then make it an Optional like so:

```
struct ShoppingList {

    var shoppingListId: NSNumber?
    var title: String

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

let newList = ShoppingList(title: "Groceries")
```

Just realize shoppingListId will be nil till you set it to something, and everywhere you use it you should bind the value in an if let.

Comment: Another interesting thing I noted is that if I create an instance of ShoppingList using "let" and then try to assign the properties it errors out saying that the instance has to be "var" instead of "let". I have edited the original question with code to illustrate it better.

Comment: @johndoe "Another interesting thing I noted is that if I create an instance of ShoppingList using "let" and then try to assign the properties it errors out saying that the instance has to be "var" instead of "let"" - it is _not_ "interesting". It's how Swift works. Maybe you should learn the language instead of thrashing around like this.

Comment: Yes indeed, if create with let, the object will be totally immutable. If you want to change it, use var.

Comment: I was making that point because in classes you can change the properties even if you make them using "let". Of course this is because classes are ref types and structs are value types.